# Show that if $A$ is an $n$ by$ $n symmetric matrix and $\lambda \neq \mu$ are eigenvalues of $A$, then $ E_\mu \subset (E_\lambda )^\perp $.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I started off as:
Let  $v\in E_\lambda$ . Given $u\in E_\mu$, $\left< u , v \right> = 0 $ because $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal. My question is that since the inner product of $u$ and $v$ is zero, would that suffice to conclude that $u$ is an element of $ (E_\lambda) ^\perp $? If not, what would be a better way to go about proving the statement above?

Comment: Do you mean $v \in E_\mu$? Also, by what reason do you conclude that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, I meant that u is an element of $E_\mu$. For the second part, I thought there was a proposition that states that the eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal, but I might be wrong.

Comment: No, you're right, but I this exercise is just rewording that same proposition, so I thought you were supposed to prove the proposition.

Comment: But, if we take the proposition for granted, then you should start by assuming you have some fixed $u \in E_\mu$, and show that $u \in E_\lambda^\perp$. By definition, this means that $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in E_\lambda$. This is more or less what you've said, but structured a little more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like $ =\lambda\langle v,w\rangle=\langle \lambda v,w\rangle  =\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^tw\rangle =\langle v,Aw\rangle =\langle v,\mu w\rangle=\mu\langle v,w\rangle $ to get $\langle v,w\rangle =0$, for the respective eigenvectors.

And yes, this means $E_{\mu}\subset E_{\lambda}^{\perp}$.